# Issue when trying to retrieve individual values from a csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am facing a issue when using d3.csv, and I would like some help to understand what I made wrong.
The purpose is to retrieve values from a csv files (attached):

```
group, axis, value, description  
FX002 (MOE) C3,Mass,4,total  
FX002 (MOE) C3,Volume,3,total  
...
```

Using a html file with javascript and d3.js with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function initialize()
        {
    d3.csv("FX002_C3.csv", function (d){
        console.log(d);
        console.log(d[1].value);
        });
    }
    initialize()
  </script>

</head>

<body>
</body>



</html>
```

I don't understand why I get the array of objects d, but that values are not accessible.
What is wrong in my piece of code ?

[result with undefined output for the expected value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axDob.png)

To debug I use Firefox console on Windows

Regards,

Eric

Comment: Avoid calling the parameter as `d` in your `d3.csv` function. Try to follow some conventions, so, when people read your code, they will focus on *what you are saying* and not *how you are saying*. Thus, use `function(data)`, or `function(dataset)` or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the spaces in `group, axis, value, description` inside the csv file. Delete those spaces after the commas and you will be fine.

Comment: @E.Thomas if that solved your problem can you accept this answer by clicking the tick on the left?